# Deserialize XML same nodes to list

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse some XML in my program, but I cannot seem to figure out the 
 best way to do this.

I try to put  `[XmlElement("CategoryMapping")]` or `[XmlArrayItem("CategoryMapping")]` on `CategoryMapping` element and it return empty list.

My class:

```
public class GetCategoryMappingsResponse
{
      [XmlElement("CategoryMapping")]
      public List<CategoryMapping> CategoryMapping { get; set; }
      public string CategoryVersion { get; set; }
}
public class CategoryMapping
{
      [XmlAttribute]
      public string id { get; set; }

      [XmlAttribute]
      public string oldID{ get; set; }
}
```

The xml:

```
<GetCategoryMappingsResponse 
  xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-29T22:17:19.611Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1077</Version>
  <Build>E1077_CORE_API6_18790878_R1</Build>
  <CategoryMapping id="1245" oldID="32775"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="177022" oldID="163848"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="177022" oldID="163849"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="16191" oldID="32777"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="12930" oldID="163850"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="48707" oldID="163852"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="16191" oldID="32781"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="40059" oldID="163854"/>
  <CategoryMapping id="40065" oldID="163855"/>
</GetCategoryMappingsResponse>
```

Comment: copy and paste your xml to => https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ and then press **Convert** button then you will get proper model for your xml

Comment: Why don't you try populating your model with some data and writing it out. That should show you any differences in the XML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I faced the same problem,
I used RestSharp and they have a problem with deserialization nodes into a list.
In order to solve it,

you should add this attribute above the property:

```
[XmlElement("CategoryMapping")]
```

then for deserializing the xml, try this code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TResponse));
TResponse result;
string content = response.Content.Replace(" xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\"", "");
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(content))
{
  result = (TResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

don't forget to add the following line before the deserialization:

```
string content = response.Content.Replace(" xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\"", "");
```

otherwise it won't work 
(I have already tried to add root attribute with namespace but it didn't work).

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is namespace. Either you can add root atribute with namespace

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")] //<-- here
public class GetCategoryMappingsResponse
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("CategoryMapping")]
    public List<CategoryMapping> CategoryMapping { get; set; }
    public string CategoryVersion { get; set; }
}
```

or initialize xml serializer with default namespace:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetCategoryMappingsResponse), "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
var result = serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(@"pathToXml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this models for deserializing;

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="CategoryMapping", Namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
public class CategoryMapping {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="oldID")]
    public string OldID { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="GetCategoryMappingsResponse", Namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
public class GetCategoryMappingsResponse {


    [XmlElement(ElementName="Version", Namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
    public string Version { get; set; }     
    [XmlElement(ElementName="CategoryMapping", Namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
    public List<CategoryMapping> CategoryMapping { get; set; }

}
```

For deserializing xml,look at the this code;

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetCategoryMappingsResponse));

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(@"<GetCategoryMappingsResponse xmlns=""urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents""> <Timestamp>2018-10-29T22:17:19.611Z</Timestamp> <Ack>Success</Ack> <Version>1077</Version> <Build>E1077_CORE_API6_18790878_R1</Build> <CategoryMapping id=""1245"" oldID=""32775""/> <CategoryMapping id=""177022"" oldID=""163848""/> <CategoryMapping id=""177022"" oldID=""163849""/> <CategoryMapping id=""16191"" oldID=""32777""/> <CategoryMapping id=""12930"" oldID=""163850""/> <CategoryMapping id=""48707"" oldID=""163852""/> <CategoryMapping id=""16191"" oldID=""32781""/> <CategoryMapping id=""40059"" oldID=""163854""/> <CategoryMapping id=""40065"" oldID=""163855""/> </GetCategoryMappingsResponse>"))
            {
                var result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```

Comment: How do you deserialize xml?

Comment: restsharp desrialize

Comment: Can you share your RestSharp request and deserializing code with me or can you try my deserializing method?